# Failing promise gets catched by the Application.onerror function

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1, promise, winjs, winjs-promise

There's this weird behavior which I don't know if it is supposed to be happening or it's a [winjs](/questions/tagged/winjs) bug.

I'm using the [`WinJS.UI.Pages.render`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh770580.aspx) to render the content of a page under a specific element.

The problem I'm facing is that no matter if I handle the failing of the `render` function, the 'error' keeps propagating and it gets "catched" by the [`onerror`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh974768.aspx) function.

Here's a quick view of my code:

```
function goFunction() {
    WinJS.UI.Pages.render('otherpage.html', root).then(null, failedNavigating);
}

function noGoFunction() {
    WinJS.UI.Pages.render('missingpage.html', root).then(null, failedNavigating);
}

function failedNavigating() {
    console.log('failed to navigate');
}

WinJS.Application.onerror = function (args) {
    debugger;
};
```

The `otherpage.html` page exists so the rendering gets executed and everything is fine. But the `missingpage.html` does not exists. In that case the `failedNavigating` function executes, so far so good, but then the `WinJS.Application.onerror` handler gets 'called'.

Is that how that is supposed to work? What am I missing?

Here's a full [project](http://1drv.ms/1CQcT2b) with a repro in case anybody wants to take a look at it.

Comment: Something else is going on here. Even if you didn't have `.then(null, failedNavigating)` there it _still_ shouldn't have triggered `WinJS.Application.onerror` since it's `.then` and not `.done` and WinJS promises aren't smart enough to figure out it's done on their own. I suspect that WinJS.UI.Pages.Render calls `WinJS.Application.onerror` directly and regardless of whether or not you handle the error.

Comment: I can't find anything in the WinJS source code to back that up though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got around to debugging this in your GitHub issue. It's because WinJS.UI.Pages.render implicitly creates a Page, which by default has an error handler that creates an Error promise, which Application was detecting as an "unhandled error promise" since nothing was continuing off of it.

You can work around it for now with something like this:

```
function noGoFunction() {

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define('missingpage.html', {
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("Page failed to load");
        }

    });

    WinJS.UI.Pages.render('missingpage.html', root).then(null, failedNavigating);
}

function failedNavigating() {
    console.log('failed to navigate');
}
```

Comment: Cool! Good to know. The workaround is no good to me cause I need something more generic. missingpage.html is what I used for the sake of the sample, but it could actually be anything I'm not aware of. Will it be threated as a bug?

Comment: This would be a breaking change to Pages.ready(), so it would have to be opened as a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Only the .done has the ability to catch and throw an error.

see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211867.aspx for the differencies.

As you can see the two are almost identical apart from this: "After the handlers have finished executing, this function throws any error that would have been returned from then as a promise in the error state." that is only present in the .done.

Try to replace you .then with a .done and see if it works.

Comment: see my other answer, I would still use a done though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229728.aspx

```
promise.then(onComplete, onError, onProgress).done( /* Your success and error handlers */ );
```

> onComplete
>
> Type: function
>
> The function to be called if the promise is fulfilled successfully with a value. The value is 
>   passed as the single argument. If the value is null, the value is
>   returned. The value returned from the function becomes the fulfilled
>   value of the promise returned by then. **If an exception is thrown while
>   this function is being executed, the promise returned by then moves
>   into the error state.**

So basically this happens because you have null in the onCompleted parameter of the .done

Try replacing it with a function instead

Comment: no, still same thing. I agree in my sample the done is enough. But I simplified it for the sake of the sample. You can download the project and try it yourself